# Resource bundles and SessionLocaleResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have searched this site (and others) but have been unable to find solution to this.
Or, the solution I found looks similar to how I am doing it.

Anyway, after a user logs in I am updating their locale based on their profile preferences. In this case I need to update a user to 'fr_FR' French. What's interesting is, after the user logs in the first page is English, but if you navigate away the page changes to French and if you go back the original page is now French.

When the user logs in they go through the HomeController which is setting/updating the SessionLocaleResolver to what should be French, but the next page doesn't reflect this!!.

```
final LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);



   if (localeResolver != null) {
  // get the new locale name from the request param, if possible
  final String newLocaleName = userProfile.getDefaultLocaleId();
  if (newLocaleName != null) {
    final LocaleEditor localeEditor = new LocaleEditor();

        localeEditor.setAsText(newLocaleName);
        // set the new locale
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response,
            (Locale) localeEditor.getValue());                                                                          
  }
    }
```

Configuration
    
       
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">

```
<bean id="messageSource"  class="
     com.ecommerce.web.util.MyResourceBundleMessageSource" >        
        <property   name="basenames" >
    <util:list>
      <value>resourcebundles.mybundles-ui</value>
      </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="localeResolver"        
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" > 
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

This was a question similar to mine, but unless I am reading it incorrectly I think I am doing things correctly.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?36339-Multilanguage-in-Session-with-SessionLocaleResolver

I am not sure what I am missing here....